# Pandas Data Frame grouping label

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple orders, A B and C.

Each order can have multiple entries, i.e. you can order several products in a basket
I've left spaces in the the dataframe just to make it clearer

```
   Order_ID     Pen Pencil
    Order_A      1    0
    Order_A      1    0

    Order_B      1    0
    Order_B      1    0
    Order_B      0    1

    Order_C      0    1
```

I'd like to make a third column which is dependent on what items are in the basket as a whole. So if there are only pens in the basket, this column is Pens Only, and if there's a mixture, it will say Pens and Pencils

example output

```
   Order_ID     Pen Pencil   output 
    Order_A      1    0      pen Only
    Order_A      1    0      pen only

    Order_B      1    0      pens and pencils
    Order_B      1    0      pens and pencils
    Order_B      0    1      pens and pencils

    Order_C      0    1       pencil only
```

Comment: Why is there singular pen in the first group but plural pens in the second?

Answer (score 1):

You can `melt`, filter, aggregate as string and `merge`:

```
df.merge(df.melt('Order_ID', var_name='output')
           .query('value == 1')
           .drop_duplicates()
           .groupby('Order_ID')
           ['output'].agg(', '.join),
         left_on='Order_ID',
         right_index=True
        )
```

Or, for fun, using a dot product:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Order_ID').transform('max')

df['output'] = df2.dot(df2.add_suffix(', ').columns).str[:-2]
```

Output:

```
  Order_ID  Pen  Pencil       output
0  Order_A    1       0          Pen
1  Order_A    1       0          Pen
2  Order_B    1       0  Pen, Pencil
3  Order_B    1       0  Pen, Pencil
4  Order_B    0       1  Pen, Pencil
5  Order_C    0       1       Pencil
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform` to get the total sum and apply a pre-defined function:

```
def pen_pencil(row):
  if (row.Pen.sum() >= 1) and (row.Pencil.sum() >= 1):
      return 'pens and pencils'
  elif row.Pen.sum() >= 1:
      return 'pen only'
  elif row.Pencil.sum() >= 1:  
      return 'Pencil Only'
    
df.groupby('Order_ID', as_index=False).transform('sum').apply(pen_pencil, axis=1)
```